# Delete complete one string from a paragraph

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a paragraph from which i want to delete a complete one string when user press single backspace. 
For example like in yahoo mail. when we compose an email and write email address at "To or CC or BCC" section(s), when user press single backspace the complete email address is deleted. 
I want that functionality but in paragraph.

Comment: i think you mean you want to delete characters in a string until you hit a `space` char

Comment: not a single character, complete word from a string

Comment: i didn't write a single char i wrote characters.  take a look at my answer for example

Comment: for example: Computer an electronic device which is capable of receiving information (data) in a particular ....                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                 
I want to delete a word from above given paragraph in single backspace. if user wants to delete the word "information", user click from mouse near particular then user press backspace from this backspace hit the complete word "information" is deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing e-mail addresses on backspace is just a deletion of characters until you hit a `space` (or `;` depends on your use case) char.
So basically what you are really asking here is:
How to `substring` the last portion of a string while the `space` character is the delimiter.
Here is a simple snippet as example:
**EDIT**:
I've updated the snippet to support caret (cursor) position while clicking the backspace or delete keys.

```js
$('#delete').on('click', function(){
var $input = $('#mystring');
var nextStr = deleteUpToSpace($input.val());
  $input.val(nextStr);
});

$('#mystring').on('keyup', function(e){
  var currentCursorPoisitoin = this.selectionStart;
if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46){ // backspace or delete keys
   var $input = $(this);
   var nextStr = deleteBasedOnPosition($input.val(), currentCursorPoisitoin);
$input.val(nextStr);
  }
});

function deleteUpToSpace(str){
var index = str.lastIndexOf(" ");
var nextStr = str.substring(0, index);
return nextStr;
}

function deleteBasedOnPosition(str, position){
var strUpToPosition = str.slice(0, position);
  var lastIndexOfSpace = strUpToPosition.lastIndexOf(" ");
var strToRemove = strUpToPosition.substring(lastIndexOfSpace, position);
  var nextStr = str.replace(strToRemove, "");
  return nextStr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="mystring" value="this is a test string">
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

Comment: for example: Computer an electronic device which is capable of receiving information (data) in a particular .... I want to delete a word from above given paragraph in single backspace. if user wants to delete the word "information" , user click from mouse near particular then user press backspace from this backspace hit the complete word "information" is deleted

Comment: i've edit my answer to support `backspace` and `delete` keys

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to remove a word when backspace is clicked.
You can use this code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<textarea id="foo"></textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener("keydown",function(event){

        if(event.code=="Backspace"){
            var text=document.getElementById('foo').value;
            var lastspace = text.lastIndexOf(" ");
            var updateStr=text.substring(0,lastspace);
            document.getElementById('foo').value=updateStr;

        }
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to identify the separator that separates these different entities. For instance, if you need to remove the last sentence in a paragraph, the separator is the period (or full-stop, as some may call it). 
Then, you can split the string by the separator, remove the last two elements (because the last element is essentially a non-completed) and then rejoin.

```
text.split('.').slice(0,-2).join('.') + '.'
```

If your separator was a period. Or generally,

```
text.split(separator).slice(0,-2).join(separator) + separator
```

See this JS Fiddle I made for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/tt24kfng/1/

An interesting thing you could try out would be to remove the last completed entity and keeping the last incompleted intact.